# Splitting strings within a dataframe in R

Tags: r, string, split

I've imported my CSV file into R as a data frame and I have assigned my column of interest (`AtollInservice$Antenna`) as a factor.

The original CSV file has the following format in my column of interest:

```
COM_CVV65BSX-M\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02
```

As you'll notice there's a single "\" in my original file yet upon importing read.csv and using the head() function R seems to have duplicated the backslash such as below:

```
> head(AtollInService$ANTENNA)
[1] COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 
    COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 
    COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02
[4] COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 
    COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 
    COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02
```

There's duplication at the beginning of the string in the file and I wish to retain everything beyond the \ or \ such that COM is the manufacturer, CVV65BSX-M is model, 2100 is the band and T02 is the tilt.

I tried incorporating Hadley Wickham's colsplit function within a transform function but I kept being prompted for additional information which I couldn't crack.

If anyone has a suggestion as to how I can split this particular column in my original data frame I would be delighted to hear from you. Attached is a link to a sample of the data that I am using and wish to split, in particular column "P" is of interest.

This is the data frame I am working with right now:

```
AtollInService <- with(Atoll, Atoll[!grepl("[_()]", NOMINAL_ID) & grepl("InService", MILESTONE) & grepl("^[A-Z][A-Z][0-9]{4}$", NOMINAL_ID) & !grepl("[L18]+[L08]", THREE_G_CELL_ID), ])
```

Could I incorporate a string split function just after the end square bracket and the end closed bracket?

[Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzkBEqPfozOOenJja01wd010a2s/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You don't have duplicate slashes \ in your imported data. R prints a single slash as \\ since a slash can be used for special characters like a line-break `\n` or a tab `\t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose this is your original data frame(simplified to two columns to illustrate):

```
AtollInservice
#                                   ANTENNA MILESTONE
# 1 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService
# 2 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService
# 3 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService
# 4 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService
# 5 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService
# 6 COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 NoService
```

Here is an option with `data.table` package where you can filter and create new columns quite easily, this assumes the `ANTENNA` column always have the same format and you can use `tstrsplit` with regular expression `_|\\\\` which split on either `_` or `\\` and then take the last four elements as columns:

```
library(data.table)
(setDT(AtollInservice)[grepl("InService", MILESTONE)]
                     [, c("manufacturer", "model", "band", "tilt") := 
                        tstrsplit(ANTENNA, "_|\\\\")[3:6]][])

#                                   ANTENNA MILESTONE manufacturer      model band tilt
#1: COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService          COM CVV65BSX-M 2100  T02
#2: COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService          COM CVV65BSX-M 2100  T02
#3: COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService          COM CVV65BSX-M 2100  T02
#4: COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService          COM CVV65BSX-M 2100  T02
#5: COM_CVV65BSX-M\\COM_CVV65BSX-M_2100_T02 InService          COM CVV65BSX-M 2100  T02
```